# Convert Table in Second Normal Form

Tags: sql, database-normalization

Please convert the following table into second normal form. i don't understand how to convert the following table in 2nd normal form.

Table Name: Students (Std_id, Std_name, Course_id, Course_credit_hour_, Course_code, Course_name, teacher_name)

So above table name student has seven attributes. so please explain how this can be converted into second normal form.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming. This is the analysis and design of the databases. You should ask on [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hi. Please read hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Say what reference you are following and/or quote the definitions & processes you are following & show where you are stuck. We are not here to rewrite your textbook or do your homework. Moreover this is a faq. Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Answer (score 1):

A student can have several courses, this will lead to unwanted redundancy. The table can be divided into following three tables:

> Students (Std_id, Std_name)
>
> Course_taken (Std_id, Course_id)
>
> Courses (Course_id, Course_credit_hour_, Course_code, Course_name,
> teacher_name)

Assuming that each course will have only one teacher.